# Similar SQL queries in different methods

Tags: java, sql, jpa

There are two similar methods:

```
Collection<Movie> findAll(UserDetails userDetails); //find all movies rated by User
Collection<Movie> findAll(UserDetails userDetails, String s); //find all movies rated by User and containing "s" in title
```

So, the second is first + regex.
JPQL code respectively:

```
select movie........ //doesn't mater
//the same logic
```

and

```
select movie........ where lower(movie.title) like :s
//the same logic
```

All the difference is one line of code, but it forces me to code repeating in these two methods. How can I avoid code repeating in this case?

I thought to implement private method that will receive the queries from these two and process "the same logic". Is it good approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the both methods and just create another method which receives your result and process the data.

```
Collection<Movie> findAll(...) { // your params here
Result result = select movie........ //doesn't mater
return processData(result);
}
```